# Connect four - finding the winning Processing (Java)

Tags: java, object, for-loop, processing

I'm building a connect 4 game using Processing (Java) and have come to a holt when trying to find the winner. I've posted the code could anyway tell me why this isn't working? or how I would remedy it.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

```
  if (whooseWon() == true) {
    text = loadFont("Tahoma-Bold-50.vlw");
    textFont(text, 50);
    fill(255, 0, 0);
    game = false;
    if (whoWon == 1) {
      text("Red Wins!", width/4, height/4);
      text("Click to play again", 110, height/2);
    } else if (whoWon == 2) {
      fill(255, 255, 0);
      text("yellow Wins!", width/4, height/4);
      text("Click to play again", 110, height/2);
    } else if (whoWon == 3) {
      fill(255, 255, 0);
      text("It's a Tie", width/4, height/4);
      text("Click to play again", 110, height/2);
      }
      }
      }
      // click to play again functionality
      void mousePressed() {
      if (game == false) {
      game = true;
      setup();
       } 
      }

     // 21 vertical possibilities, 24 horizontal and 12 diagonally that's a       total of 69 possibilities
// cols = j
// rows = i
     boolean whooseWon() {
  // horizontal
     for (int i = 0; i < rows-3; i++) {
     for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
      //red player
      if (piece[i+1][j].getColour() == color(counter1)  && piece[i+1].    [j].getColour() == color(counter1) && 
        piece[i+2][j].getColour() == color(counter1) && piece[i+3][j].getColour() == color(counter1))
      {
        whoWon = 1;
        return true;
      }
      if (piece[i][j].getColour() == color(counter2)  && piece[i+1][j].getColour() == color(counter2) && 
        piece[i+2][j].getColour() == color(counter2) && piece[i+3][j].getColour() == color(counter2))
      {
        whoWon = 2;
        return true;
      }
    }
  }
  // vertical

  for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < cols-3; j++) {

      //red player
      if (piece[i][j].getColour() == color(counter1)  && piece[i][j+1].getColour() == color(counter1) && 
        piece[i][j+2].getColour() == color(counter1) && piece[i][j+3].getColour() == color(counter1))
      {
        whoWon = 1;
        return true;
      }
      if (piece[i][j].getColour() == color(counter2)  && piece[i][j+1].getColour() == color(counter2) && 
        piece[i][j+2].getColour() == color(counter2) && piece[i][j+3].getColour() == color(counter2))
      {
        whoWon = 2;
        return true;
      }
    }
  }
  //diagonal
  for (int i = 0; i < rows-3; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < cols-3; j++) {
      //red player
      if (piece[i][j].getColour() == color(counter1)  && piece[i+1][j+1].getColour() == color(counter1) && 
        piece[i+2][j+2].getColour() == color(counter1) && piece[i+3][j+3].getColour() == color(counter1))
      {
        whoWon = 1;
        return true;
      }
      if (piece[i][j].getColour() == color(counter2)  && piece[i+1][j+1].getColour() == color(counter2) && 
        piece[i+2][j+2].getColour() == color(counter2) && piece[i+3][j+3].getColour() == color(counter2))
      {
        whoWon = 2;
        return true;
      }
    }
  }
  //diagonal
  for (int i = 0; i < rows-3; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
      //red player
      if (piece[i][j].getColour() == color(counter2)  && piece[i+1]
[j-1].getColour() == color(counter2) && 
        piece[i+2][j-2].getColour() == color(counter2) && piece[i+3]
[j-3].getColour() == color(counter2))
      {
        whoWon = 1;
        return true;
      }
      if (piece[i][j].getColour() == color(counter2)  && piece[i+1].   [j+1].getColour() == color(counter2) && 
        piece[i+2][j-2].getColour() == color(counter2) && piece[i+3]
[j-3].getColour() == color(counter2))
          {
            whoWon = 2;
            return true;
          }
        }
      }
     return false;
    }


`
```

Comment: What's the result of the code as-is?  My mind doesn't make a very good java interpreter.

Comment: @DanFarrell it's apart of a much bigger chunk of code, but at the moment I keep getting an error saying "arrayindexoutofbounds 6" I think that answers your question? Thanks

Comment: An error!   Great!  We definitely need to see the full error message to help you.

Comment: It's bad practice to have a function which returns something (other than `void`) **and** has a side-effect (sets the `whoWon` in your case) **at the same time**. Why not simply return the `whoWon` and `-1` if nobody has won yet? Apart from that I try to parse your code now :)

Comment: `rows-3;` `piece[i+3]` that won't work as in Java arrays are indexed from `0`. (of course it depends, my intuition says that `rows == n`; while the array is indexed `[0..n-1]`; however the declaration of `rows` is not included in your example.

Comment: @D.Kovács thanks for you comment, so you suggest I assign whowon as -1 and then return it as different value in a void function if someone has won ?

Comment: @HarrySayers yes; but that's independent of your problem if your problem is indeed an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. About the rule I mentioned, see [this SE](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/289952)

Comment: @DanFarrell It only says `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException 6`.

Comment: @D.Kovács thanks, I'll try changing it to what you suggest.

Comment: @HarrySayers: Ok, it's an AIOOBE, but at which line?

Comment: @D.Kovács I think it's line 24 and 25, is it because my for loops aren't right so when I'm adding to I or J it's going past the las actual index in my 2D object array???

Comment: @HarrySayers I don't know which lines are 24 and 25 (in the copied text if I guess the line numbers correctly than they are `}` and `}` respectively). But yes, my guess is, that you miscalculate the running index in your loops. See my previous comments.

Comment: I still can't work out what going with my for loops, does anyone else know? my 'piece[I][j]' object array builds a 6 row 7 column grid?

Answer (score 1):

You're making it pretty hard for people to help you. Instead of posting a disconnected snippet from your huge sketch, try to create an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). This usually involves starting over with a blank sketch and only adding enough code to repeat the problem, without any of the extra stuff not directly related to it. We should be able to copy and paste the code into our own editors, hit run, and see the same thing as you. Otherwise we're all just guessing. You'll often solve your problem in the process of creating an MCVE!

That being said, I can help you try to debug your problem. You've said that you're getting an `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds` exception. Which line is the error on? I'm not asking that so you tell me. I'm asking that because it's the first question you should be asking yourself.

When you get it narrowed down to a specific line, then you need to backtrack to find out exactly what's going on. What indexes are being accessed? How many indexes do the arrays have? You've got a mismatch between the two, which is causing your problem.

Use the `println()` function to print out every value that might be part of this. That's at least the `i` and `j` variables, as well as `row` and `columns`, and `piece.length` and `piece[yourIndexHere].length`.

Then walk through your code line-by-line until you understand exactly what it's doing. Again, you'll have much better luck if you work from an MCVE instead of trying to parse through a big mess. Then if you get stuck, you can post a new question with that MCVE and it'll be much easier for us to help you. Good luck.